# OBIEE RPD: Snowflaked table not showing up as a fact table in the BMM layer

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, obiee, snowflake-schema, oracle-analytics

I am using the RPD tool to create a data model for a database which has 6 tables.

**Dimensions** : ProductFamily, ProductionLine,Company,CurrencyExchange

**Facts**: WorkOrderStats, WorkOrder

[image]

But, WorkOrder is not getting taken as a fact table in the BMM layer.
How do I make the WorkOrder as a fact table in the BMM layer?

Any input is sincerely appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's not how facts work in OA. Facts never join to facts. Ping me on slack. I created that exact RPD last Friday.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join your fact table to an other fact table you have to create an other alias for your fact, the new alias will act as a dimension. in your case create an alias for F_workorder name it Dim_workorder for exemple and join your F_workorderStat to this dimension and keep F_workorder and it's relations just remove the relation between F_workorderStat and F_workorder it's not going to work that way.

Comment: "the new alias will act as a dimension" - not entirely true. Physical object layers do not inherently become dimensions or facts. It all depends on usage. In this case the "fact" table will act as a a passthrough mechanism for the join path in the LTS in order to be able to correlate WorkOrderStat with Company. That alias is neither a fact or a dimension but merely a crutch to compensate for a poor data model.

Comment: i didn't mean that , what i meant is that you have to make it act as a dimension to avoid the relation between two facts.

Comment: And i am telling you that in this case it doesn't "act like a dimension". It is just a passthrough table for the joins because the first fact itself does not have a relation to the company dimension.

Comment: Ok i get it, i usually migrate the foreign key of the dimension from the master to the detail fact (duplication) to allow a direct join if there is no degenerated dimensions in the master fact (no need for the fact to act as a dimension).